# Compare items of an object array in JS (2nd)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to solve this problem ([Compare items of an object array in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70609692/compare-items-of-an-object-array-in-js#70609692)) and do not understand why this doesn't work:

```js
var same = [
  {floor: '1', id: '10165', label: 'Elutuba/Köök'},
  {floor: '1', id: '10166', label: 'Tuba 1'},
  {floor: '1', id: '10167', label: 'Vannituba'},
  {floor: '1', id: '10167', label: 'Vannituba'}
];

var notSame = [
  {floor: '1', id: '10165', label: 'Elutuba/Köök'},
  {floor: '1', id: '10166', label: 'Tuba 1'},
  {floor: '1', id: '10167', label: 'Vannituba'},
  {floor: '2', id: '10167', label: 'Vannituba'}
];

function allSameFloor(a){
    const firstFloor = a[0].floor
    return a.every((item)=>{
        item.floor === firstFloor
    })
}

console.log(allSameFloor(notSame)) // false as expected
console.log(allSameFloor(same))    // <-- false ??? expected true
```

Comment: `item.floor === firstFloor` You're missing a `return` here

Comment: ok, that easy!  Thanks

Comment: If that solved it, we can close this as a typo

Comment: Ok, do I have to do anything?

Comment: Yes, @NicholasTower's suggestion will get the result you wanted

Comment: @Kinglish I think they meant "do i have to do anything *to close it as a typo*"

Comment: Yes I tested it and it gives the correct result.  How do I close the case now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a return in the function's return.

```js
var same = [
  {floor: '1', id: '10165', label: 'Elutuba/Köök'},
  {floor: '1', id: '10166', label: 'Tuba 1'},
  {floor: '1', id: '10167', label: 'Vannituba'},
  {floor: '1', id: '10167', label: 'Vannituba'}
];

var notSame = [
  {floor: '1', id: '10165', label: 'Elutuba/Köök'},
  {floor: '1', id: '10166', label: 'Tuba 1'},
  {floor: '1', id: '10167', label: 'Vannituba'},
  {floor: '2', id: '10167', label: 'Vannituba'}
];

function allSameFloor(a){
    const firstFloor = a[0].floor
    return a.every((item)=>{
        return item.floor === firstFloor
    })
}

console.log(allSameFloor(notSame)) // false as expected
console.log(allSameFloor(same))    // <-- false ??? expected true
```